# How to reset PIXI.utils.TextureCache?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm using [PIXI](http://pixijs.github.io/docs/) for a small game, and after a fight finishes, I destroy all of the JavaScript classes I've created, but texture caches of *PIXI* will remain and in the next fight characters (created by [PIXI.sprite](http://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html)) start with their last [frame](http://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.Texture.html) position in the previous fight.

I've tried to reset PIXI.utils.TextureCache like:

```
for(key in PIXI.utils.TextureCache) {
  PIXI.utils.TextureCache[key].destroy();
  PIXI.Texture.removeTextureFromCache(key);
}
```

but starting next fight I got this error:

```
Resource with name "animations/person-1.json" already exists
```

in which person-1.json is one of my animations from prevous fight.

How could I reset PIXI catches for next fight?

Comment: Are you using PIXI.MovieClip for your animations?

Comment: @Karmacon no, I have a sprite sheet containing all of frames of animation, and I'm using the frame property of PIXI.sprite, then I'm changing x and y property of frame in  an interval to show next frame of sprite sheet every time.

Comment: You should consider using a MovieClip instead. It is built to make frame animations simple for you. You can even change the animation speed. http://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.extras.MovieClip.html As for your question, I think you should show some of the code where you are loading the Sprite animation.